# wp_update_post () not accepting tax_input when not logged in or from command line

Tags: php, wordpress

Writing an import script for WordPress and the import works correctly from a browser window when logged into the same WordPress site.  However executing the script from the command-line (or from an icognito window) only partially works.  It does everything except update the "cheatsheetcat" taxonomy.

I suspect is has something to do with the "public" flag, but I don't fully understand.

Taxonomy setup as follows:

```
function pios_add_cheatsheet_taxonomy()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => 'Cheat Sheet Categories',
        'singular_name'     => 'Cheat Sheet Category',
        'search_items'      => 'Search Cheat Sheet Category',
        'all_items'         => 'All Cheat Sheet Categories',
        'parent_item'       => 'Parent Cheat Sheet Category',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Cheat Sheet Category:',
        'edit_item'         => 'Edit Cheat Sheet Category',
        'update_item'       => 'Update Cheat Sheet Category',
        'add_new_item'      => 'Add New Cheat Sheet Category',
        'new_item_name'     => 'New Cheat Sheet Category',
        'menu_name'         => 'Cheat Sheet Category',
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => true,
        'public'            => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy('cheatsheetcat', 'attachment', $args);


    //Add the parent categories
    $ar_parent_categories = array("Item category", "Industry", "Family", "BeerWine");

    foreach ($ar_parent_categories as $category) {
        $item_term = term_exists($category, 'cheatsheetcat', 0);

        // Create state if it doesn't exist
        if (!$item_term) {
            $item_term = wp_insert_term($category, 'cheatsheetcat', array('parent' => 0));
        }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'pios_add_cheatsheet_taxonomy');
```

The section of the import script that I believe is failing is:

```
$custom_tax = array(
    'cheatsheetcat' => $arTaxCheetSheet
);

//Update the attachment / post
$attachment = [
    'ID'           => $id,
    'post_title'   => $filename,
    'post_content' => $content,
    'post_excerpt' => $excerpt,
    'tax_input'    => $custom_tax,
];

$post_id = wp_update_post ($attachment, true);

if (is_wp_error($post_id)) {
    $errors = $post_id->get_error_messages();
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error;
    }
}
```

The $arTaxCheetSheet at this point is correct, having print_r'd it to the screen.  But there is something deeper with WordPress I'm missing.

Any insight would be amazing.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the user with [wp_set_current_user](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_current_user/) at the beginning of the script solved the issue for me.